# Poisson or normal regression

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

I am dealing with some count data. I can express it as frequency and do normal regression, or put the counts in Y (outcome) and the denominator as an offset and do Poisson regression. The latter has the advantage that for some samples we have sparse data (few counts), and this kind of uncertainty is lost if we work with frequencies & normal regression. On the other hand, I know that the relationship between Y (as frequency) and the predictor variables is very linear, making it a good target for normal regression. Does this linearity make Poisson (or NB) inappropriate? Should I transform the predictor variables? I've been reading this thread and it helped but still am not sure about these questions: [What advantages does Poisson regression have over linear regression in this case?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49198/what-advantages-does-poisson-regression-have-over-linear-regression-in-this-case)

If of any interest, I get more significant p-values with Poisson & Negative binomial regression than with Normal regression. And there's not much overdispersion in the data

**After comments, addition**. I've done a simulation to try to understand better how I could use a Poisson distribution for linear data. I am regressing the number of mutations vs age, simulating a perfectly linear relationship (although the way I modelled it was not perfect, there's more variance in mutation counts in older ages).

```r
mut_counts = rpois(100, 20)
ages = round(runif(100, 10, 100))
final_mut_counts = mut_counts * ages
plot(ages, final_mut_counts)
# Ok,looks good

linear = lm(final_mut_counts ~ ages -1)
summary(linear) #  --> 20 muts/year, all good. Let's try to reproduce this result with Poisson regression (with the intention of using an offset in the future to properly model uncertainty).

mb_pois = glm(final_mut_counts ~ ages -1, 
               family = poisson(link = "log"))
summary(mb_pois) # --> age estimate is 9.040e-02. Exponentiating 1.094612. Increase in muts per year about 9.4% . 
# If at age 50 num muts is 100, at 51 would be 109.4, at 52 119.8, .. at 60 : exp(10*9.040e-02) = 2.469461, this is a 247% increase, from 100 to 347 muts. 
# Makes no sense

mb_pois_exp = glm(final_mut_counts ~ exp(ages) -1, 
                   family = poisson(link = "log"))
summary(mb_pois_exp) # --> exp(age) coefficient estimate is 2.825e-43... Exponentiating turns into 1... Makes no sense. No increase with exp(age)?

mb_pois_log = glm(final_mut_counts ~ log(ages) -1, 
                   family = poisson(link = "log"))
summary(mb_pois_log) # --> log(age) estimate is 1.7177723. Exponentiating turns into 5.57. This means 457% increase with log(age) unit
# If at 50 has 100 muts, at 60 would have log(60-50) * 4.57 * 100 = 1000 muts. Makes no sense!
```

I cannot make a transformation to "age" that keeps the Poisson model right.

Am I doing something wrong in my interpretation of coefficients or is it that Poisson regression cannot be used for linearly related data?

Comment: just two points 1) if you're married to normal, you could use weights to indicate the number of counts that went into a frequency to maintain good UQ (this actually helps mean estimates too) 2) if the loglink of a Poisson is undesirable, logging predictor variables may help (if appropriate).

Comment: It’s also possible to run a regression with a Poisson likelihood and an identity link. This risks predictions less than zero, yes, but such a risk might be worth it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments. I added some simulation data in the question in case you could help me understand this

Comment: "More significant p-values" are for sure not a reason to prefer a model. In fact you do the analysis because you don't know the truth already, therefore you can't know whether "more significance" is in fact a good thing. Generally if models are chosen based on p-values, this means that these p-values will be biased by selection.

Comment: The most important thing in my view here are diagnostic plots that could tell you about the appropriateness of the different model assumptions. Also as the data are counts and Poisson seems reasonable, the Poisson regression would be my first choice to look at, and I'd consider other models only if I find that assumptions of the Poisson regression are clearly  inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks Christian, but I am not sure how that answer my question. There is a linear relationship between the response and predictor variable. Normal regression allows me to infer a meaningful slope. I tried different approaches with the Poisson regression to try to obtain sensible coefficients (unsuccessfully). I know Poisson would be better for counts data (also allowing to model uncertainty through an offset) but if the Poisson regression doesn't fit naturally the data, it won't be appropriate.

Comment: Did you try Poisson regression with an identity link function?

Comment: Nice, that works! I understand now what Dave suggested. I get the expected coefficient. Awesome! I'll play now with uncertainty using an offset. Should I be worried that normal regression gives me an AIC much lower than Poisson regression?

Comment: It depends on how the AIC is calculated. Usually, it uses the log-likelihood of the corresponding distribution family so generally, there are not easy to compare as they are not exactly like-for-like comparisons. There are some RSS-based formulas and one can use those but they assume "Gaussian data" (residuals). Depending on your analysis project thought AIC might irrelevant anyway.